# Change div value based on total of several radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have several radio button in table. how javascript or jquery can add this radio button value and change the default total value without click submit button. I mean when user click a radio button it automaticly change the value in total_score div

```
   <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="1">1
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="2">2
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="3">3
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="4">4
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="1">1
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="2">2
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="3">3
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="4">4
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" height:;">
      <div id="total_score" name="total_score" align="center">
        <h3>0</h3>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I found below coding is good but it not change automaticly the default div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var evaluation_1_1 =  $('input[name="evaluation_1_1"]:checked').val();
        var evaluation_1_2 =  $('input[name="evaluation_1_2"]:checked').val();
var totals = parseInt(evaluation_1_1) + parseInt(evaluation_1_2);
        alert(totals);
        document.getElementById("total_score").innerHTML = totals;
        }
```

Comment: you are using **radio button** `only one value will be selected at a time` why you need total? it is more like getting the value of selected radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:radio` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) to find all the radio element then subscribe to its change event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var evaluation_1_3 = $('input[name="evaluation_1_3"]:checked').val() || 0;
    var evaluation_2_1 = $('input[name="evaluation_2_1"]:checked').val() || 0;
    var totals = parseInt(evaluation_1_3, 10) + parseInt(evaluation_2_1, 10);
    $("#total_score h3").html(totals);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="1">1
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="2">2
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="3">3
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_1_3" value="4">4
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="1">1
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="2">2
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="3">3
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="evaluation_2_1" value="4">4
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" height:;">
      <div id="total_score" name="total_score" align="center">
        <h3>0</h3>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your coding is right but i have problem when when i selecting first radio button the value is NAN.. when i click both it show the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function total() {
   var sum  = 0;
   $('input[type="radio"]:checked').forEach(function(el) { sum += $(el).val(); });

   document.getElementById("total_score").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

`$('input[type="radio"]').on('click' , total)`;

```
console.log(total());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[name*=evaluation_1],input[name*=evaluation_2]').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click',function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        var totals = parseInt($('#total_score').text())+ parseInt(thisValue);
        $('#total_score').find('h3').text(totals);
        });
        });
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_1_3" name="evaluation_1_3" value="1" >1<br></td>
                <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_1_3" name="evaluation_1_3" value="2" >2<br></td>
              <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_1_3" name="evaluation_1_3" value="3" >3<br></td>
             <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_1_3" name="evaluation_1_3" value="4" >4<br></td>

    <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_2_1" name="evaluation_2_1" value="1" >1<br></td>
                <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_2_1" name="evaluation_2_1" value="2" >2<br></td>
                <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_2_1" name="evaluation_2_1" value="3" >3<br></td>
                <td> <input type="radio" id="evaluation_2_1" name="evaluation_2_1" value="4" >4<br></td>

<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" height:;"><div id="total_score" name="total_score" align="center"><h3>59</h3></div></td>
```